# Procurando letras num array criado por números aleatórios

Tags: javascript, array

Eu criei um array com valores aleatórios entre 65 e 90 e transformei ele em um array de letras. Até ai tudo certo. Como faço para encontrar nesta lista (se existir porque foi criado aleatoriamente) onde se forma a palavra DAD quando o laço for lendo cada índice (letra) um à um.

```
let tabNombres = [];
let tabLettres = [];
let voyelles = 0;
let lettreE = 0;

//random numbers array
//Nombres aléatoires 65 à 90
for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    tabNombres.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * ((90 - 65) + 1) + 65));
    }

// turning numbers into letters
// characters table
for (let j = 0; j <tabNombres.length; j++) {
    tabLettres.push(String.fromCharCode(tabNombres[j]));
}

// triying to find D, A, D sequence
for (let i = 0; i<tabLettres.length ; i++){
    for(let j=0; j<i; j++){
        for(let k=0; k<j; k++){
            if (tabLettres[k] === 'D' && tabLettres[j] === 'A' && tabLettres[i] === 'D'){

            }
        }
    }
    document.write(tabLettres.indexOf(i));
}
```

Comment: Seja bem vindo! agora leia esse manual de como perguntar. https://pt.meta.Sstackoverflow.com/questions/1084/como-devemos-formatar-perguntas-e-respostas?cb=1

Comment: Creio que o resultado está no if: `if (tabLettres[k] === 'D' && tabLettres[j] === 'A' && tabLettres[i] === 'D'){
   //aqui certo, neste caso, vc tem que saber o índice de cada letra.
            }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu código pode ser simplificado usando da sintaxe ES6:

```js
// Cria um array de 1000 caracteres pseudo-aletórios no intervalo [A-Z]
let tabLettres = [...Array(1000)].map(x => String.fromCharCode(~~(Math.random() * 26) + 65));

// Itera por tabLettres menos os seus dois últimos itens 
for (let i = 0; i < tabLettres.length - 3; i++) {
  // Compara apartir do item iterado com a sequencia DAD
  if (tabLettres[i] === 'D' &&
      tabLettres[i + 1] === 'A' &&
      tabLettres[i + 2] === 'D') console.log(`DAD encontrado no índice ${i}.`); // Se a sequencia for encontrada informa no console sua posição
}
```

A probabilidade de ocorrência da combinação `DAD` não é das mais altas então aqui vai a imagem do resultado.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Outra possibilidade de verificação do algorítimo é aplicar o script em um intervalo mais restrito de letras. Por exemplo [A-F]:

```js
// Cria um array de 1000 caracteres pseudo-aletórios no intervalo [A-F]
let tabLettres = [...Array(1000)].map(x => String.fromCharCode(~~(Math.random() * 6) + 65));

// Itera por tabLettres menos os seus dois últimos itens 
for (let i = 0; i < tabLettres.length - 3; i++) {
  // Compara apartir do item iterado com a sequencia DAD
  if (tabLettres[i] === 'D' &&
      tabLettres[i + 1] === 'A' &&
      tabLettres[i + 2] === 'D') console.log(`DAD encontrado no índice ${i}.`); // Se a sequencia for encontrada informa no console sua posição
}
```

**Referências:**

- [Sintaxe de Espalhamento](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)
- [What does ~~ (“double tilde”) do in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4055633/what-does-double-tilde-do-in-javascript)
- [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [Tabela ASCII](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)

Comment: Muito obrigado pela sua resposta, aprendi muito.

Answer (score 0):

é bem improvável desse teste bater, quando temos um algoritmo com muitas condições uma boa pedida seria diminuir essas condições em seu teste.

```js
let tabNombres = [];
let tabLettres = [];

//random numbers array
//Nombres aléatoires 65 à 90
numeroAleatorio = function() {
for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
      tabNombres.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * ((90 - 65) + 1) + 65));
    }
}

// turning numbers into letters
// characters table
letraAleatorio = function() {
for (let j = 0; j <tabNombres.length; j++) {
    tabLettres.push(String.fromCharCode(tabNombres[j]));
}
}
const filtroDAD = (arr) => {
    let totalD = 0
    let posicao = 0
    for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
        if(arr[i] == "D" && arr[i+1] == "A" && arr[i+2] == "D") {
            totalD +=1
            posicao =i
        }
        
    }

    return `Total DAD ${totalD} sua posição é ${posicao}`
}

numeroAleatorio()
letraAleatorio()
console.log(tabLettres)
console.log(filtroDAD(tabLettres))
```

nesse código você pode utilizar menos condições em sua comparação

```
const filtroDAD = (arr) => {
let totalD = 0
let posicao = 0
for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
    // Deixar apenas duas condições para testar e obter mais probabilidade de acerto
    if(arr[i] == "D" && arr[i+1] == "A") {
        totalD +=1
        posicao =i
    }

}

return `Total DAD ${totalD} sua posição é ${posicao}`
```

}

em meus testes apenas uma vez obtive a saída esperada do algoritmo.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Muito obrigado André pela sua resposta, e instrução.

Comment: se achar que a resposta foi correta pode marca-la, obrigado.